# How to detect change at current cursor position in TextWatcher Android?

Tags: android, textwatcher

In my app user can type `#` in `MultiAutoComplete` and suggestion from server will be displayed with text provided after `#`. For example :

User types `#foo`, and server returns to `MultiAutoComplete` text such as `#food` `#football`.

Now everything works fine, if cursor is at the end of the text. Proper method is getting last word, detects if it starts with `#` and sends it to server. The problem begins when user is editing text and sets cursor somewhere in the middle. `TextWatcher` detects only last word, so it doesn't see changes.

The only solution I see, is to save whole text every letter, and compare everytime to see a change.

Do you know any solution for this?

My `TextWatcher` looks like this :

```
TextWatcher tagsWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String tag = getLastTag(s);
            if (tag.length() > 0) {
                TagServerService.getTags(tag, city, tagListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: `"How to detect change at current cursor position in TextWatcher Android?"` use a `SpanWatcher`

Comment: @pskink how do you attach `SpanWatcher` to `AutoComplete`?

Comment: "When an object of this type is attached to a **Spannable**, its methods will be called to notify it that other markup objects have been added, changed, or removed." you dont attach to `AutoComplete` but to its `Spannable` text